# The `specialize` tatic in Coq does not work well with typeclasses?

Tags: coq, typeclass

I have a simple question about using the `specialize` tactic in Coq for typeclass-based code. Specifically, I am using stdpp and I have a type `lcmm_memory` that is defined to be `gmap nat lcmm_val`.

Why doesn't the first way to instantiate the hypo H below work? Looks like the `with (...:=...)` syntax does not work well with typeclasses or am I missing something?

```
Definition comp (μ1 μ2 : lcmm_memory) :=
 μ1 ∪ μ2. 

Theorem foo : forall A (μ μ1 μ2 : lcmm_memory),
 (forall μ, A μ) -> A (μ1 ∪ μ2).
Proof.
 intros ? ? ? ? H.

 (* "Cannot infer the implicit parameter
    Union of union whose type is 'Union lcmm_memory'
    (no type class instance found) in environment: [...]" *)
 Fail (specialize H with (μ:=μ1 ∪ μ2)).

 (* But this works? *)
 specialize (H (μ1 ∪ μ2)).
 Undo.

 (* This works fine (since no typeclass lookup really here): *)
 specialize H with (μ:=comp μ1 μ2).
 Undo.
 
 (* E.g. the remember tactic seems to work well with typeclasses: *)
 remember (μ1 ∪ μ2) as μtmp.
 specialize H with (μ:=μtmp).
 subst μtmp.
 
 (* etc. *)
 assumption.
Qed.
```

Comment: This is probably due to the way `with` parameters are elaborated. You should consider filling a bug report to see if coq team thinks this is to be fixed.

Comment: @PierreCourtieu OK, thanks, will file a bug!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filed as a bug/feature request at https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/18711, so marking this question as solved.